# Adding whole lines of a dataframe via a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I had code as follows to collect interesting rows into a new dataframe:

```
df = df1.iloc[[66,113,231,51,152,122,185,179,114,169,97][:]]
```

but I want to use a for loop to collect the data. I have read that I need to combine the data as a list and then create the dataframe, but all the examples I have seen are for numbers and I can't create the same for each line of a dataframe. At the moment I have the following:

```
data = ['A','B','C','D','E']

for n in range(10):

  data.append(dict(zip(df1.iloc[n, 4])))

df = pd.Dataframe(data)
```

(P.S. I have 4 in the code because I want the data to be selected via column E and the dataframe is already sorted so I am just looking for the first 10 rows)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: sorry but what is the question here? Perhaps this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, in the end I used nlargest which solved the problem: df2 = df1.nlargest(10, 'E')['A']
df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1, how="left")

Comment: awesome! you may want to post it as a self-answer, in case others have similar issues.